# MySQL Case - set column with multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, case, mysql-5.7

I have a table like below that I need to update the yes or no column based on num1/num2 criteria.

table1:

```
num1, num2, total,  y_n
   1,    2,    15, NULL
   2,    2,     8, NULL  
   3,    1,     9, NULL
   4,    1,    23, NULL
```

num2 is a process id column that will have pairs of duplicates.

The duplicate pairs point to two unique numbers in the num1 column.

The total is the required comparison column to identify which process is using the most resources.

Example output:

```
num1, num2, total,  y_n
   1,    2,    15,    y
   2,    2,     8,    n  
   3,    1,     9,    n
   4,    1,    23,    y
```

How can I create an update table statement to mark the y_n column based on the totals.

End state request: 
Which num1 total is greater than the other num1 total, where the num2 items are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self-join.

```
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.num2 = t2.num2 AND t1.total > t2.total
SET t1.y_n = 'y', t2.y_n = 'n'
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3zz1if4CcDrdMjzmPT8HPC/0)

Answer (score 1):

In the update statement you need a left join of the table to the max values of total grouped by num2:

```
update tablename t
left join (
  select num2, max(total) total
  from tablename
  group by num2
) g 
on g.num2 = t.num2 and g.total = t.total
set t.y_n = case 
  when g.num2 is null then 'n'
  else 'y'
end;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jKgGZwihBrY6DjiR9rHSJ1/0).
Results:

```
| num1 | num2 | total | y_n |
| ---- | ---- | ----- | --- |
| 1    | 2    | 15    | y   |
| 2    | 2    | 8     | n   |
| 3    | 1    | 9     | n   |
| 4    | 1    | 23    | y   |
```